# When using the direct comparison test, can the larger function be larger only after a certain value?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Example:

> Determine whether $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{n+5}{\sqrt[3]{n^7+n^2}}}$ is convergent or divergent.

**NOTE: My question remains, but ignore everything below here (I was looking at the wrong graph when writing this):**

---

Is this valid (ignoring the lack of detail)?

${\dfrac{n+5}{\sqrt[3]{n^7+n^2}}} < \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ for $n>6.068$

And $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{n^2}} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$ (convergent)

$\therefore\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{n+5}{\sqrt[3]{n^7+n^2}}}$ is convergent

Comment: No, for large enough $n$, your $n$-th term is $>1/n^2$. Limit-comparison is the thing for such problems.

Comment: The idea is correct (referring to the title); changing a sum by any finite number (a finite sum of finite things is still finite) doesn't have an effect on convergence.

Comment: I was looking at a graph for $\dfrac{1}{n}$ thinking it was $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$. My bad. If I were to use the comparison test, what function should I compare it to?

Comment: Try something like $n/\sqrt[3]{n^7}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \geq 5$,

$$\frac{n+5}{\sqrt[3]{n^7+n^2}} < \frac{n+5}{\sqrt[3]{n^7}}\leq\frac{2n}{n^\frac{7}{3}}=\frac{2}{n^\frac43}$$

Hence by $p$-series test, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{n+5}{\sqrt[3]{n^7+n^2}}}$  converges.